# Composer - solve "locked at" / "required as" limitations

Tags: php, composer-php

In my application, my requirements "could not be resolved to an installable set of packages", since

```
- Can only install one of: myNameSpace/myRepository[dev-branch2, dev-branch1].
- Can only install one of: myNameSpace/myRepository[dev-branch2, dev-branch1].
- Can only install one of: myNameSpace/myRepository[dev-branch2, dev-branch1].
- Installation request for myNameSpace/myRepository dev-branch2 -> satisfiable by myNameSpace/myRepository[dev-branch2].
- Installation request for myNameSpace/myRepository (locked at dev-branch1, required as dev-branch2) -> satisfiable by myNameSpace/myRepository[dev-branch1].
```

I get this error when I execute `composer update myNameSpace/myRepository`. In my application's `composer.json` as well in the `composer.json` of a dependent package, `myNameSpace/myRepository` is defined with `dev-branch2` - the only traces of `dev-branch1` are to be found in my `composer.lock`, and thats propably what "locked at dev-branch1" means.

How do I solve that, i.e. make composer perform an update without being resricted by limitations of my `composer.lock`?

---

What I found out:

changing this part of my `composer.lock`

```
        "name": "myNameSpace/myRepository",
        "version": "dev-branch1",
```

to

```
        "name": "myNameSpace/myRepository",
        "version": "dev-branch2",
```

solves the issue, but I assume that's not the way composer is meant to work.

Comment: If you run `composer why myNameSpace/myRepository`, you will see why the package is installed. Maybe you have another depency that require this package too,.

Comment: yes, but that is not the issue. Neither of these dependencies require dev-branch1